# How can I fix this error and what does it mean?

Tags: c

error: lvalue required as left operand of assignment

So i wrote these on top of the program:

```
#ifndef IV
#define IV 109
#endif
```

In the main function, I got the above error on this line:

```
IV='h';
```

Please?

Answer (score 3):

`IV` is a macro, which the preprocessor substitutes for its value `109`, so the compiler in turn sees:

```
109 = 'h';
```

Which is not allowed, because you can't assign to a constant.

Comment: how can I change the value of the constant?

Comment: @Manuel you can't, that's why it's called a constant, because its value never changes. Use a [variable](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/C_Programming/Variables) instead

Comment: ^^ best statement EVER.

Answer (score 2):

The preprocessor is extending:

```
IV = 'h';
```

to:

```
109 = 'h';
```

which is logically and syntactically incorrect. An `int` literal cannot be assigned to a `char` literal.

> So how can i change the value of IV?

I'm afraid you don't understand the concept of types in C. You should be using a variable in there:

```
unsigned int IV = 109;
```

Comment: So how can i change the value of IV?

Comment: @Manuel: Define it as a variable rather than a preprocessor directive.

Comment: @Manuel you can't... You shouldn't #define IV as a pre directive if you wish to change it later